# After the finale of Dark, does Winden still have a nuclear power plant?

Tags: dark

In *Dark*, we see The Unknown force the mayor of Winden to sign a building permit for the nuclear power plant.

After the finale,

> The Unknown is erased from the restored timeline, along with his parents,

so he can't have done that.

Does Winden still have a nuclear reactor?

Comment: According to the wiki, it's The Unknown who forces the mayor to back the construction of the nuclear power plant: https://dark-netflix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Unknown. If you take The Unknown out of the equation, it sounds like the coal plant blocks the construction.

Comment: @just_happen_to_know yes, that's exactly my question.

Comment: Regina not being sick also implies that the power plant wasn't built

Comment: It's an interesting question, there is a slight hitch here too. The time chair experiments which left the 2 children's bodies back on the 1953 construction site, also caused issues for Berndt Doppler.  He was giving a ground breaking/ investor speech the day after and everyone was distracted by the crime scene.  The argument could be made that the intervention by the unknown was as a result of the time chair experiments. Remove the experiments, remove the need for the strong arming of the mayor.

Comment: @McFuu good point, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @just_happen_to_know: we don't know how Regina got her cancer though

Comment: @Taladris that's true. I was making a leap based on timeline with nuclear plant (cancer), and timeline w/o nuclear plant (no cancer). It's probably not enough evidence to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that without Unknown to force the mayor to sign the document, the nuclear plant was never built in the origin timeline. There's an intersection with three traffic lights that we periodically see in the series, and long shots always show the two cooling towers in the background, one of them directly above the left light, as in the screenshot from [this site](https://fotostrasse.com/locations-series-dark-berlin/):

[image]

And here's a screenshot showing the intersection in 1987, from episode 5 of season 2:

[image]

In the final shot of Jonas and Martha as they disappear, we see the same sort of long shot of the intersection with the three traffic lights (the bus stop seems to be positioned differently in the origin world, directly facing down the length of one of the roads leading away from the intersection rather than being positioned on the side of that road and facing its opposite side as in the 1987 shot, but the position of the traffic lights and the street light on the pole is the same in all these shots). But here, you can see that directly over the left traffic light there's just a patch of moonlit sky with no silhouette of a cooling tower (click to see a larger version of this image, and you may need to turn up your screen brightness):

[image]

I think it's implied that this is why Regina doesn't get cancer in the origin timeline, while she does in the two timelines of the knot--either she developed it from living around a nuclear plant her whole life, or her mother was already doing work at the plant before she was conceived and it affected her ova.

In the final dinner scene in the origin timeline we also see a family picture of Regina, Claudia, and Bernd, he looks like he's dressing more casually than in the other timelines where he ran the nuclear plant and was always seen wearing a jacket and tie:

[image]

Comment: I thought about that final scene, but the plant isn't visible _at all_ in the scenes there, even when they talk to the son. And it is a dark and stormy night, of course.

Comment: @SQB -- Doesn't the fact that the "plant isn't visible at all" imply it didn't exist in that timeline? Or are you saying it's so dark that the plant wouldn't be visible even if it *were* still there? If the latter, that's why I picked a moment where the rain had stopped and the sky had cleared enough for a patch of moonlit clouds to be visible, wouldn't that patch be at least partially blocked by the cooling tower if the plant still existed at the same location? (again, I recommend clicking the image to see a larger version, maybe turning up your screen's brightness too)

Comment: I mean that I would expect it to be visible before the family was saved, then disappear in a cloud of golden dust. But now that I think of it, there may not have been one to begin with?

Comment: "But now that I think of it, there may not have been one to begin with?" Yeah, I'm saying it wouldn't have been there in the first place, even before Jonas and Martha arrived, since Unknown hadn't traveled to the origin timeline to make sure the mayor signed the document. The only way it could make sense for it to be there in the origin timeline but disappear after Jonas and Martha prevented the accident would be if it had been built thanks to the intervention of another traveler from the knot like Unknown, but obviously Eva didn't know about the origin timeline so how could he go there?

Comment: (cont.) On the other hand, if it had been built in the origin timeline *without* the influence of any travelers from the knot--which is the scenario I thought you were asking about--then there would be no reason for it to disappear after Jonas and Martha prevented the accident and erased the knot timelines, it would still be there blocking the moonlight in that shot. But since it isn't, it seems this scenario is ruled out (though I suppose we can't prove it wasn't built at a different location).